# MySQL import csv only gets half the lines

Tags: mysql, import, csv

I use the following command to read in a csv:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/Tyler/Desktop/players_escaped.txt' 
INTO TABLE players
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '^'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The csv looks like this:

```
^1^,^False^,^False^,^Ovie^,^Soko^,^6^,^8^,^210^,^^,^M^,^London^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^0^,^2009^,^^,^False^,^False^,^{299F909C-88D9-4D26-8ADC-3EC1A66168BB}^,^844^,^2013^,^^,^^,^0^,^^,^^,^2011-02-16 20:53:34.877000000^,^^,^2011-02-16 20:53:34.877000000^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^1^,^2^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^
^2^,^False^,^False^,^Jordan^,^Swing^,^6^,^6^,^200^,^^,^M^,^Birmingham^,^AL^,^35218^,^^,^^,^0^,^2009^,^^,^False^,^False^,^{299F909C-88D9-4D26-8ADC-3EC1A66168BB}^,^844^,^2013^,^^,^^,^0^,^^,^^,^2011-02-16 20:53:34.877000000^,^^,^2011-02-16 20:53:34.877000000^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^1^,^2^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^
```

I also tried `\` as a delimiter and got the same results.

I'm only getting the odd numbered rows.

There are 250k records in the csv.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to check the last character of each line

Instead of this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/Tyler/Desktop/players_escaped.txt'  
INTO TABLE players 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
ENCLOSED BY '^' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Try this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/Tyler/Desktop/players_escaped.txt'  
INTO TABLE players 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
ENCLOSED BY '^' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Yep, the file came from a Windows System.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Do not use command line, it need set up environment parameter to allow you import from local csv file.

Instead use import wizard is much easier for me.
[image]

However I only import first 100 lines.

I solve it by choose latin1 instead of default utf-8

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89044

[image: default utf-8 not work, latin1 works]